# Pytorch runs on GPU without CUDA

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I'm scratching my head a bit. I just got a new work computer and am trying to actually set up a clean CUDA environment this time. So far all I've done is the following:

Downloaded pytorch with `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`

Run the following script:

```
def measure_time(device, size=1024*4):
    print(f"Running on {device}")
    
    # Create random matrices
    a = torch.randn(size, size, device=device)
    b = torch.randn(size, size, device=device)
    
    # Warm up the device
    for _ in range(10):
        c = torch.matmul(a, b)

    torch.cuda.synchronize() if device.type == 'cuda' else None

    # Measure the time taken for 1000 iterations
    start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(1000):
        c = torch.matmul(a, b)
    
    torch.cuda.synchronize() if device.type == 'cuda' else None
    end_time = time.time()
    
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Time taken: {elapsed_time:.4f} seconds\n")
    return elapsed_time

def main():
    # Check for the availability of GPU
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    # Perform the computation on CPU
    cpu_time = measure_time(torch.device('cpu'))

    # Perform the computation on GPU if available
    if device.type == 'cuda':
        gpu_time = measure_time(device)
        print(f"Speedup factor (GPU/CPU): {cpu_time / gpu_time:.2f}")
    else:
        print("GPU not available.")

main()
```

Output of script:

```
>>> main()
Running on cpu
Time taken: 316.8135 seconds

Running on cuda
Time taken: 31.7928 seconds

Speedup factor (GPU/CPU): 9.96
```

So it both appears to see the gpu and we see a convincing time improvement, both suggesting we have working gpu support.

From everything I see online though, this should NOT be working, e.g., [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-it-required-to-set-up-cuda-on-pc-before-installing-cuda-enabled-pytorch/60181). Is pytorch running without CUDA?

Running a tensorflow script with the same goal errors out, as it can't find the GPU.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Sure I could go and just download CUDA and get tensorflow working, but I'd prefer to actually know what my computer is doing.

Comment: This is impossible to answer, we cannot validate if you have CUDA installed or not, TensorFlow not working does not mean any CUDA version is installed, as TensorFlow requires specific CUDA/cuDNN versions installed.

Comment: I mean, it's a brand new work computer. CUDA is not installed. Obviouslly you can't look at my computer. But, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same thing recently. I am using a workstation with only nvidia driver installed on it. I tested two different containers, one based on a plain Ubuntu20.04 and the other based on [nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04](https://nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04). In both containers I install pytorch, then build my DL model. When running my model in two containers, I get exact same CPU/GPU utilization. Possible explanations for this:

1. the already existing libraries coming with nvidia driver are enough for my pytorch-based model. Perhaps my model does use some pytorch functionalities which do not require all cuda libraries.
2. pytorch installation comes with the required cuda libraries.

It should be noted, when I use another model based on tensorflow, I get an error in the case of no cuda installation.